# iterate over a row in a dataframe to change class type

Tags: r, grepl

I have a dataset containing all character values, I want to change some to factor and some to numeric depending on what is contained in the original character value (if a number is contained then convert column to numeric, if a letter is contained, factor). I have this for loop where I am sequencing along my dataset but I can't get i to return the actual cell value.

```
l <- c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0")

   
for (i in df) {
  if(i[c(1)] %in% l) {
    as.numeric(i)
  } else {
    as.factor(i)
  }
}
```

I also have tried with grepl and ifelse:

```
for (i in seq_along(df[c(0),])) {
  ifelse((grepl(l, df[i])), as.numeric(i), as.factor(i))
}
```

this is a reproducible example of the dataset:

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| true | 1 | -25.4 |
| false | 2 | 123.23 |
| false | 3 | 321 |
| true | 4 | -24 |

--for this example I would want col1 to be a factor and col2, col3 to be numeric

Comment: `grepl` doesn't work as a vectorized function with its first argument, only its third argument. Also you would have only matched the integers 1:9 if it had worked and even then it would also have classified "a1c" as "numeric".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in base R just do:

```
df <- type.convert(df, as.is = FALSE)

str(df)

'data.frame':   4 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ col1: Factor w/ 2 levels "false","true": 2 1 1 2
 $ col2: int  1 2 3 4
 $ col3: num  -25.4 123.2 321 -24
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses a function that attempts to convert to number and sum: if the result is NA, then it converts to factor, otherwise converts to number.

Then use `lapply()` and `data.frame()` to apply the function to each column of `df` and gather the results into a data frame.

```
convert <- function (x) {                                             
        if(is.na(sum(as.numeric(x[!is.na(x)])))) {      
                as.factor(x)                            
        } else {                                        
                as.numeric(x)                           
        }                                               
}                                                       

df2<-data.frame(lapply(df, convert))
```

Answer (score 0):

Doable pretty nicely with `dplyr::across`:

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
  as_tibble() %>% # to make printing show column class type
  mutate(across(1:4, as.character),
         across(5:7, as.factor))
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 32 × 11
   mpg   cyl   disp  hp    drat  wt    qsec     vs    am  gear  carb
   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <fct> <fct> <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 21    6     160   110   3.9   2.62  16.46     0     1     4     4
 2 21    6     160   110   3.9   2.875 17.02     0     1     4     4
 3 22.8  4     108   93    3.85  2.32  18.61     1     1     4     1
 4 21.4  6     258   110   3.08  3.215 19.44     1     0     3     1
 5 18.7  8     360   175   3.15  3.44  17.02     0     0     3     2
 6 18.1  6     225   105   2.76  3.46  20.22     1     0     3     1
 7 14.3  8     360   245   3.21  3.57  15.84     0     0     3     4
 8 24.4  4     146.7 62    3.69  3.19  20        1     0     4     2
 9 22.8  4     140.8 95    3.92  3.15  22.9      1     0     4     2
10 19.2  6     167.6 123   3.92  3.44  18.3      1     0     4     4
# … with 22 more rows
```

Comment: i like that but is there a way to not have to find what columns should be factor and which should be numeric by hand? it's a pretty large dataset with a lot of columns that are mixed with numbers and characters.

Comment: You might like `readr::type_convert(df)`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
x %>% mutate(across(starts_with('col1'), as.factor), across(contains(c('col1','col2')), as.numeric))
```

Of course if your `col1` is named something more unique than to all the other columns then you can try

```
x %>% mutate(across(starts_with('col1'), as.factor), across(!contains('col1'), as.numeric))
```